# If i replace "arr[index]" with "arr[items]" i get an array with the values of [ 2, 0, 3, 4 ], can someone explain what is happening

Tags: javascript, foreach

```js
const ary = [1, 5, 3]

ary.forEach(mult)

function mult(items, index, arr) {

  arr[items] = index * 2;
}

console.log(ary)
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger? You are using the `items` as an index...

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? Your `forEach` can't work, you need to specify a value for each element : `array.forEach(el => mult(el))`

Comment: @Zabon it most definitely can work. It's passing the function reference directly. Your code will eta-reduce to the call without an extra function wrapper: `array.forEach(el => mult(el))` is the exact same as `array.forEach(mult)` for any unary function. Yet OP's `mult` implementation matches the callback for `forEach`, your invocation *does not* - the correct invocation would be `.forEach((el, i, arr) => mult(el, i, arr))`

Comment: @VLAZ :o ! Well I never saw that before, apologies & thanks for the infos !

Comment: Try putting `console.log(items, index)` before the assignment, and `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))` after it. You'll be enlightened.

Comment: Thanks for the quick anwers. @Barmer if console.log(items, index) the console shows me "1, 0, 3" for the items why is it not "1, 5, 3" like in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[1, 5, 3]

In the start  items=1   index=0

arr[1]= 0*2 i,e 0

[1,0,3]

then items becomes 0   index=1
arr[0]= 1*2 i,e 2

[2,0,3]

then items becomes 3   index=2
arr[3]= 2*2 i,e 4

arr[2] remains same

items gets changed when arr[items] gets modified

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!